# What about Yukihira Soma's mother?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

I don't recall his mother being mentioned so far in the anime. Is there any info on her status/location?

Comment: Isn't she dead?

Comment: Well, she've just appeared in chapter 311. No doubt, her appreance is inherited by her son, Soma. However, there is no part of the chapter which tell if she is alive or not.

Answer (score 3):

In the end of chapter 1 of the manga is the only time I know she is mentioned (or more like shown in a picture).

[image: last page of chapter 1 of "Shokugeki no Soma"]

Answer (score 1):

In the fifth season of the anime, Soma's mother's name is revealed as Yukihira Tamako, and her status is deceased. She's the reason why Joichiro stopped traveling so much and came home - he had to take care of Soma and the family restaurant.

The [wiki](https://shokugekinosoma.fandom.com/wiki/Tamako_Yukihira) also provides some information regarding her debut in the series:

> **Manga**:
>
> - Manga debut: chapter 311
>
> **Anime**:
>
> - First mention: Episode 74
> - Cameo: Episode 76
> - Full appearance: Episode 83